# Searching for posts not marked with a certain tag

Tags: bug, tags, search

The help for the search function says clearly that the way to search for posts not marked with a tag, say [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support), is to put a hyphen before the brackets, like this:

```
-[support]
```

When I do it, something else happens: the search string in the search field gets changed to

```
"-[support]"
```

and the search instead gives me matches where the word "support" occurs, and the tag [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) may very well appear.

Am I somehow doing it wrong?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, but hard to tell when you don't give us a complete example.  A sample query like `[c#] -[.net]` reliably returns C# questions that are not also tagged with [.net].

Comment: @HansPassant: This happens when you only search for one exclude  tag: `-[.net]` alone also reproduces the problem. When you add something else to the search query, then everything works fine.

Comment: It's kind of broken. Search will return `results found containing "-[support]" tagged with not support` so there's a part of it working, but it shouldn't put quotes around it. Probably an unintended side effect of another change.

Comment: On MSE: [Without specifying another search criterion, can I see a list of questions that do not have a particular tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242132)

Comment: A simple workaround: [search for questions with 0 or more views](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A0+-%5Bsupport%5D)

Comment: I guess I tried out the construction on its own and then gave up using it when I couldn't get it to work. @HansPassant What I showed was my complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workaround, though.

To find all posts without support tag, use [`-[support] is:`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bsupport%5D+is%3A)
To find all questions without support tag, use [`-[support] is:q`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bsupport%5D+is%3Aq)